# How to link to part of the same document in Markdown from Mermaid schema block?

Tags: markdown, mermaid

Link to part of the document. It's very simple. I can make a link inside an MD document like this:

```markdown
[link](#Header1)

# Header1
```

The link from the mermaid diagram can be made like this:

```
flowchart TD
    X{{Block 1}} --> A[[Block 2]]
    click A https://stackoverflow.com/
```

What is the correct way to insert a link in a block that will go to the title of the document?

I tried inserting an internal link as shown in the second example, but the jump to part of the document does not happen